# firebreath plugin create a full screen window, but the window always under the browser window when it appers, how can I bring it to top

Tags: window, atl, firebreath, wtl

```
CaptureScreenApp app;

int MyPluginAPI::captureScreen(const FB::JSObjectPtr& callback)
{
    boost::thread cs(boost::bind(&CaptureScreenApp ::captureScreen,
        app, callback));
    return 1;
}

class CaptureScreenApp {
public:
    CaptureScreenApp() {
        HRESULT hRes;
        hRes = OleInitialize(NULL);
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));
        AtlInitCommonControls(ICC_WIN95_CLASSES);
        g_Module.Init(NULL, NULL);
    };
    ~CaptureScreenApp() {
        g_Module.Term();
        OleUninitialize();
    };

    bool captureScreen() {
        CMessageLoop theLoop;
        CMainDialog g_MainDlg;
        g_Module.AddMessageLoop(&theLoop);
        if (NULL == g_MainDlg.Create(NULL)){
            DWORD ret = GetLastError();
            return FALSE; 
        } 
        g_MainDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        g_MainDlg.UpdateWindow();

        int nRet = theLoop.Run();
        g_Module.RemoveMessageLoop();
        return TRUE;    
    };
};

class CMainDialog : public CDialogImpl<CMainDialog>
{
public:
    enum {IDD = IDD_MAIN};
    ....    
}
```

the window(the new window is a full screen window with a desktop pic as the background) I create in CaptureScreenApp::captureScreen always under the browser window when it appears(browser window always actived in other word), what ever how I set the HWND_TOPMOST for the new window. like this:

[enter link description here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZmhinLSZqbs/U756M4CFLfI/AAAAAAAAAD8/U3dF-4y11kE/s1600/%25E6%2596%25B0%25E5%25BB%25BA%25E4%25BD%258D%25E5%259B%25BE%25E5%259B%25BE%25E5%2583%258F.bmp)

how can i bring the full screen window to top when it appers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545) API lets you change Z order (make sure to read Remarks there). You create your window with `NULL` parent, so your window is completely independent from browser window, so there is nothing to push it to the front: it would be either you or interactive user.

Comment: thanks! As your suggest, use browser window as parent, chrome&firefox works, but IE still failed: the browser window is still front when call the jsapi first time, but the second time the it goes behind.

Comment: You can use Spy++ to inspect the effective layout of windows, then read carefully `SetWidnowPos` article to see your options of putting window into foreground (except/in addition to using parent window).

Comment: use the SetForegroundWindow(hwnd) I can bring the window front, but cannot keep it front when press ctrl+tab, this problem just comes on IE